# Access main class member variable from setOnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have implemented an activity with a simple `ListView`. In the `java` file, I have implemented `OnItemClickListener()` to respond to `ListView` item clicked.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private String value;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);

        value = "Hello World";

        final ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
        aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ListValues);
        listview.setAdapter(aa);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id)
            {
                // Get Item Clicked
                String ItemSelected = (String)listview.getItemAtPosition(position);

                // Access "value" containing "Hello World"
            }
        }
    }
```

I need to access member variable `value` of my `MainActivity` class in `onItemClick()`. Kindly tell me how to do it.

Comment: Have you add it to ListValues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use:

```
MainActivity.this.value;
```

Or, even simpler, just as if it was a member of the OnClickListener:

```
value
```

Will also work.

Answer (score 0):

you declared it globally so you can use it directly

```
    @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id)
            {
            //Get Item Clicked
            String ItemSelected = (String)listview.getItemAtPosition(position);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext,value,Toast.LENGTH).show();
                                                  ^
                                                 here
}
```